# Is there a way to preserve data attributes on elements of a reactive Meteor template?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, minimongo

I'm trying to build a simple game using Meteor. I have a collection of 'games', where each game has a state which is a 7x7 array of data used for a grid.

I have 3 templates, the game table, a row of that table and a cell of that table:

```
 <template name="game">
  {{#with gameObject}}
    {{name}}
  <table id="gameGrid">
    {{#each state}}
     {{> gameRow}}
    {{/each}}
  </table>
  {{/with}}
</template>

<template name="gameRow">
  <tr>
  {{#each this}}
    {{> gameSpace}}
  {{/each}}
   </tr>
</template>

<template name="gameSpace">
  <td class="game-grid-space colour-{{this}}" ></td>
</template>
```

The GameObject context in that first one is a single game from my collection - it has a name and a state which is the 7x7 array.

To deal with click events on each of the  elements, I'm assigning them a data attribute as they render, like so:

```
  currentSpaceId = 0;

  Template.gameSpace.rendered = function(){
    if(!this.rendered){
      this.$("td").data("spaceId", currentSpaceId);
      currentSpaceId++;
      this.rendered = true;
    }
  };
```

I'm not using a session here because it doesn't seem necessary but I've tried with it and have the same issue.

This is basically labelling the 49 squares from 0-48 as they render, ie in order. Then I can very easily translate that into their grid position and identify the clicked square.

The problem is that on any state change Meteor seems to re-render the whole DOM and re-call that rendered method for every square. That of course means their data attribute gets way out of whack, since it just keeps iterating. As far as I can tell the solution would seem to be if I could somehow pin those data attributes so the newly rendered dom just keeps them instead of rewriting them.

All I really want to do is change a class on each grid space based on its value in the state array (values being r=red, b=blue etc, but just being used as CSS classes) - so if what I'm doing is completely insane that would also be really helpful feedback! I'm really having trouble figuring out how I should be identifying which  is clicked though if not like this.

Thanks in advance for any help, and if I can provide any clarification I'd be happy to.

Comment: To confirm your suspicion, what you're doing is completely insane (but that's alright sometimes). For clarity - are the "cells" set to a specific value at start? Is there any other unique identification for a cell?

Comment: @LorenzoLinarducci Thanks for commenting! To be a bit clearer, I'm attempting a clone of 7x7 (http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/original/1/14761/2433052-7x7-screen03.png), so my "cells" are defined only by a background colour (which is what I'm storing as state). There's no unique identification or state of a cell beyond their position + colour. I'm probably thinking about this all wrong but a 7x7 grid of colours seemed like an obvious approach - but a unique identifier seems necessary to identify which cell is clicked, which I think is my real issue.